# How to have both Ultisnips and Emmet-Vim depending of the filetype

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-emmet-vim

I often use UltiSnips for other file types, but for HTML I'd like to use Emmet-vim.

However, I'd like to use the same trigger for both. For this I have

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<C-j>'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<C-j>'
```

in my `.vimrc`.

Unfortunately, it seems that by assigning the same trigger to both makes Emmet-vim not work (it works if I comment the UltiSnips line).

Is there a way to use `<C-j>` for both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of @MartinTournoij

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<C-F12>'
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<C-S-F12>'

function! IsEmmet(filetype)
  echom a:filetype

  if a:filetype == 'html'
    return v:true
  endif

  if a:filetype == 'css'
    return v:true
  endif

  return v:false
endf

imap <expr> <C-s> IsEmmet(&filetype) ? "\<C-S-F12>" : "\<C-F12>"
```

Comment: Nit: I prefer `v:true` and `v:false` to `1` and `0` when working with booleans

Comment: You can also use a `<Plug>` mapping that doesn't interfere with existing keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<C-F11>'
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<C-F12>'

function! SetUltiSnipsMap()
  imap <C-j> <C-F11>
endf

function! SetEmmetMap()
  imap <C-j> <C-F12>
endf

augroup snippettrigger
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter *.* call SetUltiSnipsMap()
  autocmd WinEnter *.* call SetUltiSnipsMap()
  autocmd BufWinEnter *.html call SetEmmetMap()
  autocmd WinEnter *.html call SetEmmetMap()
augroup END
```

The idea is to make vim the value of the global variable when you enter in a buffer or when you switch to a buffer of type `.html`.

The first two lines are called to restore the default first.

Comment: while this looks like exactly what I want, it doesn't seem to work. indeed I can check that the variables are defined as in your script depending on whether I'm in an html file or not. but neither ultisnips in non-html files, nor emmet in html files work with <C-j>. maybe I need to reload the plugin somewhere?

Comment: I would look in the code of the plugin to see how the plugin map the shortcut and add this code to the autocar.

Comment: @ElPC The plugins will setup the mappings when loaded, and not for every buffer, so that's why this doesn't work. What you can do is set the mappings to something you don't use (`<F13>` and `<F14>` might work), and then switch the mapping of `<C-j>` to that similar to what this answer is doing (e.g. `nnoremap <C-j> <F13>`).

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij, I have adapted the solution to your suggestion. I have tested on Windows 10 and it works fine.

Comment: This should work as well I think (didn't test): `imap <expr> <C-j> &filetype->split('\.')->index('html') == -1 ? "\<C-F11>" : "\<C-F12>"`

Comment: @Martin, I have tested and it work fine too :-)